# ext-gwt (gxt) onRender entry point class

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I have a basic class that extends `LayoutContainer` with the method `onRender`. How can I assign this as my `EntryPoint`? Traditionally I would define a class that implements `EntryPoint`, overriding `onModuleLoad`?

```
public class TheRoarChronicles extends LayoutContainer  {
    protected void onRender(Element parent, int index) {
        super.onRender(parent, index);
        setSize(600, 400);
        setLayout(new CenterLayout());

        ContentPanel panel = new ContentPanel();
        panel.setBodyStyle("padding: 6px");
        panel.setFrame(true);
        panel.setHeading("CenterLayout");
        panel.addText("I should be centered");
        panel.setWidth(200);

        add(panel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to hate me for this, but you do not want to make this class an `EntryPoint`. The fact that you're asking this question indicates that you are very new to GWT. This class defines a particular Component of your `view`--this should not be an `EntryPoint`. An `EntryPoint` should be thought of like a `main` method for a normal Java application, it is the beginning of all execution of your program. You do not want to assign a particular view Component to this role.

It'd be much cleaner to simply define an `EntryPoint` that has the sole responsibility of adding this single Component to the RootPanel, e.g.

```
RootPanel.get().add(new TheRoarChronicles());
```